# Override schemas.enable in kafka-connect connector

Tags: json, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a distributed Kafka Connect (6.x) cluster with multiple connectors installed. Key and value converters are set to `org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter`. For one of the connectors (an S3 Sink) I need to consume events without a schema, so the schemas.enable properties are set to false in the cluster configs: `key.converter.schemas.enable=False`, `value.converter.schemas.enable=False`. For others (Debezium MySql source connectors) I need to add the schema in the event, so the properties should be true.

I know that [it's possible to override configs in the connectors](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/references/allconfigs.html#override-the-worker-configuration), but apparently this only works for `producer.` and `consumer.` configs. I tried overriding `producer.key.converter.schemas.enable` in the source connectors, but it doesn't seem to have effect.

Is there a way to achieve this within a single Kafka Connect cluster?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use continue to use `key/value.converter.schemas.enable` in the respective connector configs without any prefix and that'll override the worker properties.

Converters are not properties of the consumer/producer clients

Comment: Indeed it does! Minor addition, it might be obvious: I also had to specify `key/value.converter` in the connector so `key/value.converter.schemas.enable` has effect.

Comment: The slash means either or both, not literal `key/value`